# Good Programming Practice?

Tags: c++

I was wondering what is better to do, in terms of using good programming practice. I have a class, Account. It has one data memeber, m_balance. My question is, in my member functions, should i use m_balance directly, or the member function Account::get_balance(), when i need to use the account balance to compare or whatever.

For example....

```
int Account::get_balance() const
{
    return m_balance;
}

void Account::debit( int money_value )
{
    if( money_value > 0 && money_value <= m_balance )
        m_balance -= money_value;
    else if( money_value == 0 )
        throw std::invalid_argument( "Invalid debit value" );
    else if( money_value > m_balance )
        throw std::invalid_argument( "Debit amount exceeds account balance" );
}
```

Or should i define the member function...

```
void Account::debit( int money_value )
{
    if( money_value > 0 && money_value <= get_balance() )
        m_balance -= money_value;
    else if( money_value == 0 )
        throw std::invalid_argument( "Invalid debit value" );
    else if( money_value > get_balance() )
        throw std::invalid_argument( "Debit amount exceeds account balance" );
}
```

Is one practice any better than the other? Does calling the function take more time or anything?

If that makes sense. Sorry if its confusing. I don't quite know how else to explain it.

Comment: You can put the implementation of "getBalance" in the class definition, and then the compiler is free to inline it. At that point, it is no more expensive than a direct access but has the advantage that if - in future - you need to make "getBalance" do something more complex, your users are already doing the right thing.

Comment: yeah it is in the class definition... i just wrote it like that as an example... its a member function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the implementation in a discrete compilation unit, then yes, there may be an overhead to accessing that element, since the program may have to perform a jump and return. However, it's also possible the compiler/linker can resolve this during "link time optimization".

You can also avoid this in the first place by providing an inline implementation of the getter:

```
class Account {
    double m_balance;
public:
...
    double getBalance() const { return m_balance; }
...
};
```

This is primarily about good encapsulation. When you do sloppy or partial encapsulation, you put a burden on your users to understand how the class works outside of simply accessing its members. For example, this is often the case when you return raw pointers -- the end user is now responsible for knowing whether, how and when to release the pointer value.

Plus getters are a good way of future-proofing things. Maybe in future you don't actively maintain "m_balance" or you need to add some thread-protection against accessing it. If your users are all directly accessing m_balance they'll just get bugs and weird behavior. If they are already going through getBalance they won't need to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

getBalance assures the program that no outside user/caller can use m_balance's value nefariously (i.e. changing it, etc.). The idea of a "getter" insures that all the public use of that data member is "getting", not setting.

"Does it take more time?"
Not at the cost of safety and good code. Pre-mature optimization is evil. Optimizations arise due to need more often than not. And if using a function to access the variable slows down your code, there's probably other ways to chop down on that complexity in run-time.

Comment: No problem! (Mark the question as answered if there's nothing else I can help with.)

Comment: Yes but the guy is using m_balance internally.  I think using getter/setters internally is a matter that should be decided on a case-by-case basis. I think it is very helpful when getBalance() mean more than trivial return in the future and nonsense when it will likely never change to be more than a return.

Comment: @anacy Click the check under where the answer's upvote, downvote arrows are (on top and below the 0)

Comment: I am using it internally... I'm just talking about in the .cpp file of the class definition

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue, I think the asker implies "when i need to use the account balance to compare" that he will be using m_balance for reasons not shown in the above code (comparing two accounts? perhaps) but I do agree with you that internally, getters are not necessary.

Comment: Do getters take more time when you call them multiple times in a function, opposed to just using the data member itself in the function? Everything is internal

Comment: Yes. There is overhead of calling any function in the callstack's pushing and popping of the current state of variables, etc. You mentioned "programming practice" rather than "I want to shave off every possible second" so I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I understand the least privilege principal. I'm just talking internal

Comment: Yeah, sorry... I didnt quite know how to state the question. Yeah i was just wondering which is a better habit to get into using

Comment: From http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#GettersSetters, 
In native languages like C++ it's common practice to use getters (i = getCount()) instead of accessing the field directly (i = mCount). This is an excellent habit for C++ and is often practiced in other object oriented languages like C# and Java, because the compiler can usually inline the access, and if you need to restrict or debug field access you can add the code at any time.